# Customizing Catalog Item Page

Tags: 2013, term, display-template, catalog

I have a Term-Driven SP '13 site and I am trying to customize the catalog item page. The 2 content types that exist on this site are PDF's & videos. Each content item will have a name, rating (stars), note board, and views. The videos will be viewed on the catalog item page but the documents will just provide a link for downloading.

This method seems to be the best way for me to do this but I'm having issues figuring out how to actually customize these pages:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj884105.aspx

How do I access the properties of the items in these pages?

Is it possible for me to conditionally handle my different content types within one of these pages?